# Gradle build successful but local dependencies throwing noClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, class, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I'm writing a Java program that runs from the command line and uses a library that I wrote to parse command line arguments. Since my library isn't on maven repository, I'm using flatDir in gradle to grab the jar from a directory local/ containing the jar file. Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir(dirs: 'local')
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver', version: '3.4.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.7.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.12'

    // not in maven repository
    compile 'JModule:JModule:1.3.1'

}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'dependencies'
}

build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

My code runs fine in the eclipse IDE, and runs fine from the command line when I comment out all the references to JModule (my library) and run it with all the other libraries I'm using. However, when I run it with JModule as a dependency, it produces the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jModule/def/CommandLogic
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jModule.def.CommandLogic
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I've already tried removing references to the class com.JModule.commandLogic but this only produces the same error with other JModule classes. Just to be clear, I'm not yet exporting to a jar - I'm just running the main class from the command line using the "java" command. The jar is also in the eclipse folder "project and external dependencies" so I'm assuming this means it's in my classpath, since the other jars in there run fine in my program.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks